# Android can't create files in specific folder

Tags: android

Hello I have specified a folder (later a file based on that folder locstion) and I see that the folder or file cannot be created. This is my code:

```
File folder = new File(userFolder.getPath() + "/" + "a" + "1" + "/" + "a" + "2");
```

but when I define shorter path it works:

```
File folder = new File(userFolder.getPath() + "/" + "a" + "1" + "/");
```

I was trying to take it into try/catch but no exception was thrown then.

why is that so?

Comment: `userFolder.getPath() ` Well... what would be the value? And why didn't you start your code with defining that variable? Further you should also post the code where you try to create that folder or a file.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I need to make a folders one after another I cannot do a few folders at once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

File folder = new File(userFolder.getPath() + "/" + "a" + "1" + "/" + "a" + "2").mkdirs;

folder.createNewFile;